# Cannot install a replaced go package due to verification error

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm truing to install tensorflow by replacing it with a private repo. It wont install since it says it cant read user details for my private gitlab. I've replaced https by ssh in git config and also tried enabling command prompt. Looks like the verification step fails.

```
go mod download github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
go: git.myrepos.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: verifying go.mod: git.myrepos.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/git.myrepos.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: 410 Gone
    server response:
    not found: git.myrepos.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2658c7dea94643a56da034a91ab984d322bf101412d6039a91e73001beedffd2: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.myrepos.com': terminal prompts disabled
    Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
    If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

And my go.mod

```
go 1.18


replace (
    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow => git.myrepos.com/team/tensorflow v1.0.0
)

require (
    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)
```

Here's my .gitconfig

```
➜  tensorflow cat /Users/myuser/.gitconfig
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
# Please adapt and uncomment the following lines:
    name = myuser
    email = myuser@myrepos2.com
[url "ssh://git@git.myrepos.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://git.myrepos.com/
[core]
    editor = nano
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

I've also tried this:

```
export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
```

Update:

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go 

go: github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 (replaced by git.myrepo.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0): verifying go.mod: git.myrepo.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/git.myrepo.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: 410 Gone
    server response:
    not found: git.myrepo.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2658c7dea94643a56da034a91ab984d322bf101412d6039a91e73001beedffd2: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.myrepo.com': terminal prompts disabled
    Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
    If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

To add more context. Looks like the output is the output of https://sum.golang.org/lookup/git.myrepo.com/tream/tensorflow@v1.0.0:

Notice that I replaced the true URL for privacy purposes

```
not found: git.myrepo.com/team/tensorflow@v1.0.0: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2658c7dea94643a56da034a91ab984d322bf101412d6039a91e73001beedffd2: exit status 128:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.myrepo.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

I dont understand why it tries to verify my package or how to avoid that. Clearly only I have access to it

Comment: Try running under `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`. Does it make what Git does more clearly? Is Git at all called?

Comment: (While we're at it, you do not need `env` in the last command. If an envrironment variable is `export`ed, all processes started in the shell after that, see it, so there's no need for special dances: a plain `go get ...` call would see that variable. On the other hand, there's no need to `export` an env. variable, nor is there any need to use `env`: the shell allows to call a process using `VAR1=value1 [VAR2=value2 ...] command`, and in this case the process running `command` (and only this process) will see these variables set.) To be honest, I know of no compelling reasons to ever run `env`.

Comment: updating results

Comment: Can you manually call `git ls-remote -q https://git.myrepos.com/path/to/the/repo`? Does it ask the same question about the terminal prompt being disabled? I find it odd that I see nothing resembling Git trace in your output even under `GIT_TRACE=1`.

Comment: Also, what happens if you do `git ls-remote -q ...` with a remapped URL (`ssh://git@...`)?

Comment: git ls-remote -q git@git.myrepo.com:team/tensorflow.git works ok, I see the HEAD

Answer (score 2):

Solved by exporting this env var:

```
GOPRIVATE=git.myrepo.com/team
```

From go doc https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Configuration_for_downloading_non_public_code

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by:

- Verify GOPRIVATE is well defined: `go env -w GOPRIVATE="<private_repo>/*"`
- Verify private repo is well defined at `.gitconfig`
- remove the problematic cache: `rm -rf /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2658c7dea94643a56da034a91ab984d322bf101412d6039a91e73001beedffd2`